# String manipulation required

Tags: shell

Here is a sample string . I would like to get the output from this in the specified format.

String:

/vob/TEST/.@@/main/ch_vobsweb/1/VOBSWeb/main/ch_vobsweb/4/VobsWebUI/main/ch_vobsweb/2/VaultWeb/main/ch_vobsweb/2/func.js

filename;path to file

func.js;VOBSWeb/VosWebUI/VaultWeb/func.js

The filename is listed at the end of the whole string , and it's path is supposed to be stripped using the characters after each numeric value (eg. /1/VOBSWeb/ and then /4/VobsWebUI and then /2/vaultWeb)

Comment: Ouch. I think you'd struggle to get the second part down to a single regexp - probably easier to write a few lines of perl.

Comment: What platform, tools, languages? `Shell-scripting` covers a multitude . . .

Answer (score 0):

one way

```
$ string="/vob/TEST/.@@/main/ch_vobsweb/1/VOBSWeb/main/ch_vobsweb/4/VobsWebUI/main/ch_vobsweb/2/VaultWeb/main/ch_vobsweb/2/func.js"
$ path=$(echo "$string" | sed "s|\/[0-9]\/|\n|g"|sed 's|\/.*||' | tr "\n" "/"|sed 's/\/$//')
$ echo ${path##*/}
func.js
$ echo ${path%\/*}
/VOBSWeb/VobsWebUI/VaultWeb
```